# How to mark if value continuosly frozen more than or equal to 4 times

Tags: r

Hi i have a df as below
How to create column "rep"  if values in value columns repeats >=4 tome

we can create RLE_created column with below code

```
df$RLE_created<-sequence(rle(as.character(df[,grep("Value",colnames(df))]))$lengths)

Value        RLE_created     rep
1              1             
3              1              y
3              2              y
3              3              y
3              4              y
7              1               
8              1              
8              2             
9              1              y
9              2              y
9              3              y
9              4              y
9              5              y
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please copy the output of `dput(df[1:10,])` into your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, rep :=  c("", "Y")[(.N >= 4)+1], Value]
```

NOTE:  It is better not to use function names for object names